# Javascript function navigator.getUserMedia is undefined in Safari 5?

Tags: javascript, audio, safari, undefined, getusermedia

I'm using Safari v5.1.7 on Windows 7 
I want to use the javascript function: [navigator.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia); to use media devices 
such as a camera or microphone for audio, 
The problem is that [navigator.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia) is always `undefined`

Here's my code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia (
    {audio: true}, 
    function(stream) {console.log('Stream: ' + e);}, 
    function(error)  {console.log('Error: '  + e);}
);
```

I also tried the following code, and it's also `undefined`:

```
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia       ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia    ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia );    
navigator.getMedia (
    {audio: true}, 
    function(stream) {console.log('Stream: ' + e);}, 
    function(error)  {console.log('Error: '  + e);}
);
```

**How to solve this ? 

Or what is its equivalent if this function isn't provided in Safari ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari doesn't support [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/), which is the HTML5 standard that defines [`getUserMedia`](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html). At the moment this API will only work in Firefox and Chrome.